# error TS2345: Argument of type 'StudentInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, java, android, typescript, react-native

I am getting string type when iterating over an object using map. So I am forced to use JSON.parse and then use the object fields.

Here is my component in TS causing the issues:

StudentsScreen.tsx:

```
export default function StudentsScreen(props: StudentInfoProps) {
  const {studentList} = props;
  console.log(typeof studentList);//object
  console.log(JSON.stringify(studentList)); //["{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"course\":\"Javascript\"}","{\"name\":\"Jane Doe\",\"course\":\"Typescript\"}","{\"name\":\"Greg Doe\",\"course\":\"ReactNative\"}"]
  return <> {
    studentList?.map(student => {
    console.log(typeof student);//string
    const {name, course} = JSON.parse(student); //I should not need to do this
    //const {name, course} = student; //This should be enough. However, this would cause to get undefined for name and course.
    return (
      <Student
        key={uuidv4()}
        name={name}
        course={course}
      />
    );  
  })}
  </>;
}
```

Error:

```
Screens/Students.tsx:11:53 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'StudentInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

11     const {name, course} = JSON.parse(student);
```

StudentInfo.tsx:

```
export type StudentInfo = {
  name: string;
  course: string;
};

export type StudentInfoProps = {
  studentList: StudentInfo[];
};

export type RootStackParamList = {
  ReactNative: {studentList: StudentInfoProps};
};
```

Do you what could cause to obtain a string when iterating over an object?

This object is coming from Android Native:

MyReactActivity.java:

```
public class MyReactActivity extends ReactActivity  implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Bundle initialProperties = new Bundle();
            Student stud1 = new Student("John Doe", "Javascript");
            Student stud2 = new Student("Jane Doe", "Typescript" );
            Student stud3 = new Student("Greg Doe", "React Native");
            ArrayList<String> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
            studentList.add(gson.toJson(stud1));
            studentList.add(gson.toJson(stud2));
            studentList.add(gson.toJson(stud3));
            initialProperties.putStringArrayList("studentList", studentList);
            
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "RNProject", initialProperties);
        
        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }
}
```

Here I defined the Student object in java which then is passed to React Native:

Student,java:

```
package com.rnproject.screens.reactnative.helpers;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String course;

    public Student(){}

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{name="+name+",course="+course+"}";
    }

    public Student(String name, String course){
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

Do you see any wrong with the student object that can cause to get a string during iteration with map?

Why I am not allow to do something like this?

```
const students = [{"name":"John Doe",
               "course":"Typescript"},
               {"name":"Jane Doe",
               "course":"Javascript"}]


const tmp = students.map(student => {
  const {name, course} = student;
  console.log(name);
  console.log(course);
})
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm not a Java person but isn't that `toString` supposed to return *valid JSON*? It's using `=` which is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> console.log(JSON.stringify(studentList)) // ["{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"course\":\"Javascript\"}","{\"name\":\"Jane Doe\",\"course\":\"Typescript\"}","{\"name\":\"Greg Doe\",\"course\":\"ReactNative\"}"]
> ```

Note the quotes around your curly braces, that means `studentList` is an array of JSON strings, which is why `console.log(typeof studentList)` yields `object`, since the `typeof` operator considers arrays as objects.

The reason for your TS error is that your explicit types promise TS that `studentList` is an array of objects, so each `student` should be an object, which isn't a valid input for `JSON.parse`, which only takes in strings.

When you asked

> Why I am not allow to do something like this?

You are. But the code provided after the question is not equivalent to the props you gave the component

Your code even says as much

> ```java
> initialProperties.putStringArrayList("studentList", studentList);
> ```

Your `studentList` is a String ArrayList, that's the issue.

I don't know much about Java, but since your class implements `Serializable`, my guess is you don't need to call `toJson`, let java figure serialization out, and change your arraylist to be properly typed. You may also want to look into `Parceable` rather than `Serializable` and use `initialProperties.putParceableArrayList`